# Word COM Addin : How to iterate on all parts of not consecutive selected text (Ctrl key)

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I am developing a Word 2007/2010 COM Addin which helps users to apply custom styles in Word documents.

For the moment I succeed to apply styles on consecutive selected text (even over multiple paragraphs), but when I try on not consecutive selections (texts selected in different parts of the document thanks to 'Ctrl' key), only the last selected part is styled.

How can I iterate on different selected parts when selections are not consecutive?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a Workaround I will expose below for those who are interested :

I used the WindowSelectionChange to catch each selection change in my word document where i put the code below

```
Public mySelectionStack as ArrayList

If My.Computer.Keyboard.CtrlKeyDown Then   
    mySelectionStack.Add(Sel.Range)
Else                                  
    mySelectionStack = New ArrayList()
    mySelectionStack.Add(Sel.Range)
End If
```

Then, I can do a for each on mySelectionStack to apply dedicated behavior to each part of the selection.